# Three way language dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
se_eng_fr_dict = {'School': ['Skola', 'Ecole'], 'Ball': ['Boll', 'Ballon']}

choose_language = raw_input("Type 'English', for English. Skriv 'svenska' fo:r svenska. Pour francais, ecrit 'francais'. ")

if choose_language == 'English':
    word = raw_input("Type in a word:")
    swe_word = se_eng_fr_dict[word][0]
    fra_word = se_eng_fr_dict[word][1]
    print word, ":", swe_word, "pa. svenska," , fra_word, "en francais."

elif choose_language == 'Svenska':
    word = raw_input("Vilket ord:")
    for key, value in se_eng_fr_dict.iteritems():
        if value == word:
            print key
```

I want to create a dictionary (to be stored locally as a txt file) and the user can choose between entering a word in English, Swedish or French to get the translation of the word in the two other languages. The user should also be able to add data to the dictionary.

The code works when I look up the Swedish and French word with the English word. But how can I get the Key, and Value2 if I only have value1? 
Is there a way or should I try to approach this problem in a different way?

Comment: What you mean by value1 and value2 ?

Comment: value1 = the first value in the dictionary (in this case Skola or Boll) and value2 = the second value in the dictionary (Ecole, Ballon)

Comment: Simply you can loop over your dictionary items :`>>> se_eng_fr_dict = {'School': ['Skola', 'Ecole'], 'Ball': ['Boll', 'Ballon']}
>>> val='Skola'
>>> for i,j in se_eng_fr_dict.items() :
...     if j[0]==val:
...           print i
...           print j
... 
School
['Skola', 'Ecole']`

Answer (score 0):

A good option would be to store `None` for the value if it hasn't been set. While it would increase the amount of memory required, you could go a step further and add the language itself.

Example:

```
se_eng_fr_dict = {'pencil': {'se': None, 'fr': 'crayon'}}

def translate(word, lang):
    # If dict.get() finds no value with `word` it will return
    # None by default. We override it with an empty dictionary `{}`
    # so we can always call `.get` on the result.
    translated = se_eng_fr_dict.get(word, {}).get(lang)

    if translated is None:
        print("No {lang} translation found for {word}.format(**locals()))
    else:
        print("{} is {} in {}".format(word, translated, lang))

translate('pencil', 'fr')
translate('pencil', 'se')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a set of nested lists would be better for this:

```
>>> my_list = [
    [
        "School", "Skola", "Ecole"
    ],
    [
        "Ball", "Boll", "Ballon"
    ]
]
```

Then you can access the set of translations by doing:

```
>>> position = [index for index, item in enumerate(my_list) for subitem in item if value == subitem][0]
```

This returns the index of the list, which you can grab:

```
>>> sub_list = my_list[position]
```

And the sublist will have all the translations in order.

For example:

```
>>> position = [index for index, item in enumerate(my_list) for subitem in item if "Ball" == subitem][0]
>>> print position
1
>>> my_list[position]
['Ball', 'Boll', 'Ballon']
```

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I think that would make things a bit easier. I really wanted the dictionary to work out though!

Comment: Yeah, a dictionary could work but a nested set of lists is ordered, and you don't have to worry about extracting keys from values (dictionaries are great for key to value, not value to key). Nested lists solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

i hope there could be a better solution, but here is mine:

```
class Word:
    def __init__(self, en, fr, se):
        self.en = en
        self.fr = fr
        self.se = se

    def __str__(self):
        return '<%s,%s,%s>' % (self.en, self.fr, self.se)
```

then you dump all these `Word`s into a mapping data structure. you can use dictionary, but here if you have a huge data set, it's better for you to use BST, have a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/2.0.1

lets say you have all these `Word`s loaded in a list named `words`, then:

```
en_words = {w.en: w for w in words}
fr_words = {w.fr: w for w in words}
se_words = {w.se: w for w in words}
```

again, BST is more recommended here.

Answer (score 0):

In order to speedup word lookups and achieve a good flexibility, I'd choose a dictionary of subdictionaries: each subdictionary translates the words of a language into all the available languages and the top-level dictionary maps each language into the corresponding subdictionary.

For example, if `multidict` is the top-level dictionary, then `multidict['english']['ball']` returns the (sub)dictionary:

```
{'english':'ball', 'francais':'ballon', 'svenska':'ball'}
```

Below is a class **Multidictionary** implementing such an idea.
For convenience it assumes that all the translations are stored into a text file in **CSV** format, which is read at initialization time, e.g.:

```
english,svenska,francais,italiano
school,skola,ecole,scuola
ball,boll,ballon,palla
```

Any number of languages can be easily added to the CSV file.

```
class Multidictionary(object):

    def __init__(self, fname=None):
        '''Init a multidicionary from a CSV file.
           The file describes a word per line, separating all the available
           translations with a comma.
           First file line must list the corresponding languages.

           For example: 
             english,svenska,francais,italiano
             school,skola,ecole,scuola
             ball,boll,ballon,palla
        '''
        self.fname = fname
        self.multidictionary = {}
        if fname is not None:
            import csv
            with open(fname) as csvfile:
                reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
                for translations in reader:
                    for lang, word in translations.iteritems():
                        self.multidictionary.setdefault(lang, {})[word] = translations

    def get_available_languages(self):
        '''Return the list of available languages.'''
        return sorted(self.multidictionary)

    def translate(self, word, language):
        '''Return a dictionary containing the translations of a word (in a
           specified language) into all the available languages.
        '''
        if language in self.get_available_languages():
            translations = self.multidictionary[language].get(word)
        else:
            print 'Invalid language %r selected' % language
            translations = None
        return translations

    def get_translations(self, word, language):
        '''Generate the string containing the translations of a word in a
           language into all the other available languages.
        '''
        translations = self.translate(word, language)
        if translations:
            other_langs = (lang for lang in translations if lang != language)
            lang_trans = ('%s in %s' % (translations[lang], lang) for lang in other_langs)
            s = '%s: %s' % (word, ', '.join(lang_trans))
        else:
            print '%s word %r not found' % (language, word)
            s = None
        return s


if __name__ == '__main__':
    multidict = Multidictionary('multidictionary.csv')
    print 'Available languages:', ', '.join(multidict.get_available_languages())
    language = raw_input('Choose the input language: ')
    word = raw_input('Type a word: ')
    translations = multidict.get_translations(word, language)
    if translations:
        print translations
```